# user relationships - add friend link in a content-profile node

Tags: users

I have installed the [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) module, and I have questions about how it works.

When you install the module, a "relationships" link should be added in a user profile page (users/myname), but in my case it doesn't; I've modified user-profile.tpl.php, and cleared the cache, but still the link doesn't appear. What's wrong?

How can I add a link to "add/remove friend" on a content-profile node of user? And also how to output list of user's friends? I guess a view block would help me in this situation.

Comment: Can you see the links as the admin account? Are there any configuration options that need to be set first? Have you looked into your permissions? It may be that users need to be assigned permissions before they can view the links.

Comment: 1. i Can't see the links as the admin.
2. No
3. Yes, granted permissions to all users.

Comment: Could you possibly post a link to the site?

Comment: here: http://ruh.kz

Comment: Someone help please, have searched whole drupal.org - no results

Comment: What version of Drupal?  Which version of User Relationships?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I followed the [instructions that I found in the documentation of the module](http://zugec.com/drupal-planet/how-to-install-and-setup-user-relationships), and everything worked absolutely perfect. The steps for your reference were:

1. Enabled the modules: UR-API, UR-Mailer, UR-UI, UR-Views
2. Created a new relationship (e.g. friend)
3. In Permissions make sure that you have enabled the **can have relationships** permission in the **user_relationships_api module** (this is what I forgot the first time)

The rest of the permissions are pretty straight-forward. If you follow the instructions to the letter, you will get the link in the user profile page.

P.S: The guide in the above-mentioned link has a screenshot for the required permissions: **make sure that your permissions match this screenshot's EXACTLY**.

As for the block that you want to create:

Enable the UR-blocks module. It creates sample useful blocks (including a block for each relationship that you created). You can insert this block directly in the profile node using the corresponding tpl.php file and a code like the one that you can find in this article:

[Drupal - How To Display Block In Node?](http://www.werockyourweb.com/drupal-block-in-node)

Comment: ok, 1st question is solved. Deleted modifies user-profile.tpl.php and cleared the cache, then link  become a friend bla bla appeared on user-profile.
I can easily print this link in a user-profile.tpl.php with this code:
<br />
<?php print $profile['user_relationships_ui']; ?>
<br />
Now is the 2nd question:
<br />
How can i add a link to "add/remove friend" on a content-profile node of user? And also how to output list of user's friends? (I guess views block would help me in this situation).

Comment: Ok, now i've added the link add/remove friend in a profile node. Posted my solution here: http://webcoder.kz/user-relationships-addremove-friend-link-user-profile-node

So now is the only one question remains: How to output a block of user friends in a user profile with views?

Comment: Are you using the advanced profile kit? Are you using panels? How do you get the user profile as a node (i.e. which module are you using to do that)?

Comment: I'm not using nor APK, nor panels. I'm using content_profile module to do that.

Comment: Check the additions in the edit above.

Comment: @f1234k: thanks for the answer, but what if i want a views-block? I need to display there cck imagefield such as field_photo (I use this field as user avatar).

Comment: I suppose it will not be very hard to do that either. Since the profiles in your configuration are actually nodes, you will have to create a node type of view, in Arguments use the User:id, in the Fields the fields that you want to display (i.e. you can use the cck field with the avatar etc) and in the filter "User Relationships: Relationship type: Friend (or whatever). Then, all you have to do, is embed the view in your node with the user id as an argument.